# About - Lenovo System Interface Foundation Driver

Tags: events, viewer

Yesterday I opened Event Viewer on Windows 10 and I saw some warnings and 1 error about ESENT 455 (That error was easy to fix by putting some missing files in the right place and now it's ok). Moreover, some of the warnings said that after Windows login, the performance of the cpu drops a little bit. Which is also ok, and it's due to the undervolt I've done (It is stable I tested it with 2 programs). But today another error occured about a file called "imcontroller" that stopped working, and was due to "Lenovo System Interface Foundation". Many articles say that this may be a virus. In my case it wasn't, because I scanned it with different programs. It's just a file/thing from the Lenovo Foundation. I deleted completely Lenovo Foundation from my drive, from a hidden file called ProgramData and some last files from regedit. Now the error does not come up anymore.

My question is: is it safe that I deleted Lenovo Foundation from all of these locations?

By the way the laptop seems to have the same performance as before, if not a little bit better. But I'm worried, even tho I've read that Lenovo S. I. Foundation is pre-installed and it's a program that is optional.

Comment: Lenovo files are not required to run Windows

Comment: However, you should remove the Lenovo software, the file belongs to in order to avoid any issues from the file being manually deleted

Comment: SIF should not be deleted because it is responsible for numerous driver additions. This is my experience in this situation. Did I mis-interpret you?

Comment: Ohh ok now I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yesterday I opened Event Viewer on Windows 10 and I saw some warnings and 1 error about ESENT 455
> ...
> But today another error occured about a file called "imcontroller" that stopped working, and was due to "Lenovo System Interface Foundation".
> .....
> Many articles say that this may be a virus.
> ....
>
> My question is: is it safe that I deleted Lenovo Foundation from all of these locations?

1. IM Controller can be fixed but I do not recommend removing System Interface Foundation. It looks after this, battery and other things.

   Download the newest version of SIF from Lenovo Support (V1.1.19.6 or thereabouts).

   In Device Manager, System devices, uninstall SIF.  May take 5 or 10 minutes.

   Restart and install the newest version of SIF.
2. IM Controller is definitely not a virus. I have it on my Laptops and no issue.
3. As noted above, do not delete or disable SIF.

Comment: Device Manager -> System Devices -> System Interface Foundation V2 Device
Is this the file I have to delete? And then donwload S.I.F. 1.1.19.6?

Comment: Yes. That is the version I have running on both machines here.